# Sorting Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am a php novice so please be kind.... Need to sort date, after location has been selected.

```
    <div id="enroll_now">
  <form name="enroll" id="enroll" method="post" action="<?php echo get_permalink(762); ?>">
    <p>
      <label >Class Title</label>
      <input type="text" name="class_title" value="<?php echo $title;?>">
      </input>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Choose Location</label>
      <select name="location" id="location" >
        <option selected="selected" value="0">--Select Location--</option>
        <?php
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from wp_location WHERE class_id=$page_id ORDER BY location ASC");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<option value=".$row['id'].">".$row['location']."</option>";

        }

    ?>
      </select>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Choose Date</label>
      <select name="choose_date" id="choose_date">
        <?php
        if (isset($datesavailable) && is_array($datesavailable)) {
        foreach($datesavailable as $val)
        {

        echo' <option value="'.$val.'">'.$val.'</option>\n';
 }
 }
    ?>
      </select>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="image" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/confirm.png" alt="Confirm Information" />
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

The locations sorts fine, but then when I get to the date, I need them to sort by closest date first. Any help would be appricated. Thanks.

Comment: What does the `$datesavailable` array look like?

Comment: Where are you getting `$datesvailable`? What does it contain? What kind of format of date are you trying to sort?

Comment: See this is where I get lost.  Here is the actual page http://50.22.71.94/~eptac/events/ipc-a-600-instructor/. Choose Manchester, NH and you will see the options for multiple dates

Comment: Why don't you sort dates from database?

Comment: You can sort multiple criteria with a query like this "SELECT * from wp_location WHERE class_id=$page_id ORDER BY location ASC, datefield". I saw your webpage but don't get what are you trying to do

Comment: trying to get the dates ordered by closest date on the top.  I dont have access to myphpadmin right now so I cant pull the table info to write query, but I was hoping to just use what I already have, but be able to sort the results.  I added asort($datesavailable); before the foreach statement but that didnt help.

Comment: See my answer and it that doesn't help you, edit your question adding 'admin-ajax.php'

Answer (score 1):

Use `ORDER BY somecolumn` in your query; http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: Thanks that was it, The refernece to the date was in a completely diffferent file, once I found that I was ablt to sort based upon the column.

Answer (score 0):

If the dates are just an array, you can use `asort` or `arsort`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Answer (score 0):

I examined your page and see that you're sending a POST (id & location) when the event change is triggered in your combo. My suggestion is to query the database like this

```
SELECT * from wp_location WHERE class_id=$_POST['id'] AND location=$_POST['location'] ORDER BY date
```

I'm assuming date field in your database is DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP type.

Comment: Replacing the current query I have? Thanks for your help already.

Comment: and if you don´t know the name of the datefield, submit this query to your database "DESCRIBE table_name" and you will get the info needed

Comment: No, the query in my answer is for the file admin-ajax.php, where your are returning data based on an id and location, I added to this the ORDER BY clause to sort this by date.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am just not that good at this sort of stuff.  Not sure if we are supose to solicit on here or not, but Jorge ar you on oDesk.